# calling to function in function

Tags: python

I need to build 3 funcs.
the 1st is insertion sort, 2nd is generate list of random nums between 0-1 and the 3rd need to create list of randon numbers (using 2nd func.) and sort them (using 1st func.).
I can't change the tests in the end and not the arguments of the funcs.
I have a problem with func 3, it says `NameError: global name 'my_list' is not defined`.
The other funcs works fine, where am I wrong in the 3rd?
*the 1st func not allowed to return anything.

thanks!

my code:

```
def insertion_sort(lst):
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        current=lst[i]
        j=i-1
        while j>=0:
            if current < lst[j]:
                lst[j+1] = lst[j]
                lst[j] = current
                j-=1
            else:
                break

def random_list(n):
    import random
    my_list=[]
    for i in range(n):
        my_list.append (random.random ())
    return my_list

def sorted_random_list(n):
    random_list(n)
    insertion_sort(my_list)

### TEST FUNCTION - DON'T CHANGE THIS ####
def test_sorted(lst):
    print lst == sorted(lst) and len(lst) > 0

def test_len(lst, length):
    print len(lst)==length

def sort_and_test(lst):
    lst = lst[:]
    insertion_sort(lst)
    test_sorted(lst)

sort_and_test([13,54,3434,88,334,6,8,84,57,4,2,4,6,6])
sort_and_test(["dog","cat","cow","zebra","frog","bat","spider","monkey"])
sort_and_test(["hi","hello","how are you","what your doing"])

test_len(random_list(10), 10)
lst = sorted_random_list(10)
test_len(lst, 10)
test_sorted(lst)
```

Comment: Maybe you'd consider changing the subject line? The actual problem didn't have much to do with sorting random ints.

Comment: Why would you think that my_list would be accessible outside of random_list?

Comment: You should post the full error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the quickest way is to replace the code in `sorted_random_list()` with

```
new_list = random_list(n)
insertion_sort(new_list)
return new_list
```

but the deeper problem here appears to be a lack of understanding of scoping and the need for assignment of values to variables.  `my_list` only exists within the scope of `random_list()`, so it is not available in the global namespace, which is why you are getting the error you are seeing here.  You also aren't actually assigning the result of `random_list(n)` to anything, so you are throwing away the new list.  Then you don't actually return the list created in `sorted_random_list()` in any case.

Answer (score 7):

It's because you call `random_list(n)` but you don't assign the value it returns to any variable.

Try this instead:

```
my_list = random_list(n)
```

And that should solve your problem

Without assigning the return value of `random_list()` to a variable, all you're doing is computing `random_variable()` and throwing away the result. What you want to do is to name the result of the call to `random_variable()` so that you can refer to it later. This is done by assigning it to a variable with that name, in this case, `my_list`

Hope this helps

Comment: well, now it says: 'print len(lst)==length
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()'

Comment: @user1816377 you need to return the array my_list in sorted_random_list. You are assigning lst to the return value of sorted_random_list, but because it is not returning anything, you are then testing the length on NoneType object. Changing the code of sorted_random_list to what is in sr2222's answer should help.

Comment: Yeah, because you aren't returning a value from `sorted_random_list(n)`, so the test code is passing in `None` to `test_len(lst, 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

`my_list` is not a global variable. Because you are returning the list from `random_list()`, in `sorted_random_list()` you should have `my_list = random_list(n)`. This will create the variable `my_list` within the scope of that function.